# New Year Algorithm 2019 on International Sites

Tags: discussion, announcements, international-sites

International communities have one very remarkable initiative that began several years ago on Stack Overflow in Russian: we celebrate the beginning of the new year with a contest for the best questions and answers with the [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) tag. The contest lasts for all of January and consists of two sessions: from January 1 to January 10 and from January 11 to January 31. Each session has eight nominations.

#### Why [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm)?

Many of us recall our university years with nostalgia. It is especially pleasant to remember how we were studying disciplines like discrete mathematics, the theory of algorithms, programming... I think, at work we often have a lack of academic tasks: sorting, searching for elements, permutations, etc. Questions and answers on the [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) tag might help to fill this gap.

#### Please join us in congratulating the New Year Algorithm 2019 winners!

**Author of a question with the highest score and a question that gets the most answers**

[@enxaneta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/98629/enxaneta) with a question “[Cómo dibujar un corazón: (el algoritmo del corazón)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/230120/10)” that got 24 upvotes and 11 answers!

**Author of an answer with the highest score**

[@devconcept](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2224/devconcept) with [an answer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/229007/10) to a question “[¿Cómo organizar una lista de colores de forma eficiente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/228408/10)”. The answer got 21 upvotes.

**Author of an answer to their own question, if the answer gets a higher score than any other answers to the question**

[@nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu) with self-answered question “[Git の 3-way merge とは具体的にどのようなアルゴリズムですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52019/78)”. The question got 5 upvotes and the answer got 4 upvotes.

**Author of an accepted answer with the highest score**

[@Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) with [an answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/356603/17539) to a question “[Quando e como devo usar operador instanceof e typeof no JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356582/17539)”. The answer got 14 upvotes.

**Author of a question with the most views**

[@komatsuna](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/31930/komatsuna) with a question “[クイックソートの2種類の実装法で実行速度に顕著な違いが出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52329/78)” that got 12 upvotes, 4 answers, and 452 views!

**Author of the most questions**

[@nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu) has asked 7 questions over the second session. The questions got 26 upvotes and 6 answers in total.

**Author of the most answers**

[@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) has answered 12 questions over the second session, 9 of them were accepted, the answers got 33 upvotes in total.

#### Complete list of winners

If you are interested in a complete list of winners on each site, please look at international metas:

- [Stack Overflow in Japanese](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2903/78)
- [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7516/17539)
- [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3842/10)
- [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8460/6)

---

Thanks to everyone who participated. I hope it was fun for everyone!